# Can I use Holy Water for an "additional weapon attack"?

Tags: dnd-5e, improvised-weaponry

With my 3rd level Gloomstalker, can I make a regular attack and then use Holy Water for my Dread Ambusher additional attack?

The crux of the issue is the description of Holy Water and Improvised Weapons, where it's unclear if the Holy Water can count as a weapon.

The weapon in my other hand is a hand crossbow, if that matters.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By a strict reading of the rules, [holy water](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/holy-water-flask) requires its own action to activate:

> **As an action**, you can splash the contents of this flask onto a creature within 5 feet of you or throw it up to 20 feet, shattering it on impact.

So while it seems to be able to count as a weapon attack once thrown, you must take an action to get it to that point. And [Dread Ambusher](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#GloomStalker) does not give you another action, it simply allows another standard weapon attack after you take the Attack Action:

> If you take the Attack action on that turn, you can make one
> additional weapon attack as part of that action.

Since you've already taken the Attack Action, you have no more actions to activate the holy water.

Answer (score 4):

#### RAW, Holy Water requires an action to use.

The description for Holy Water says:

> *As an action*, you can splash the contents of this flask onto a creature within 5 feet of you or throw it up to 20 feet, shattering it on impact. In either case, make a ranged attack against a target creature, *treating the holy water as an improvised weapon*. If the target is a fiend or undead, it takes 2d6 radiant damage.

Using the holy water in the way described here requires you use a full action. If you take the attack action, then technically this is a different action than the action described in the holy water description.

#### The order you do things should only matter when the rules specify that order matters.

Allowing you to use holy water as part of an attack action makes the sequence order dependent. Under this rule, if I throw holy water first, I can make no more attacks, but if I attack first, I can still throw holy water.

To be clear, my understanding of the D&D 5e action economy is that most things are order independent unless they specifically lay out the ordered conditions - this is not a rule, but a perspective on the rules in general. This is *why* I would stick with the RAW ruling I explained above.